# Display a PDF file from FTP server inside an ASPX page C#

Tags: asp.net, pdf, iframe, ftp-server, google-document-viewer

I have a PDF file on my FTP Server. I want to display the PDF file using ASP.Net.

I used google viewer in an iframe control:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=ftp://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

It worked perfectly while viewing pdfs from public servers. The problem is that I need to give ftp username and password for the pdf to be displayed on my asp.net page.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

---

Edit:

I can use
    url=ftp://username:pass@ftp.samplesite.com/...

but I dont want the username and password to be attached to the url.

I also tried this code:

```
<div><object data="ftp://username:pass@ftp.website.com/website.com/wwwroot/folderpath/test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="800" height="1000"> alt : <a href="ftp://username:pass@ftp.website.com/website.com/wwwroot/folderpath/test.pdf">test.pdf</a> </object> </div>
```

and it works well. Tho the ftp username and password are still shown in the page source. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Why can't the user view the pdf with his own favorite pdf reader application?

Comment: Because I want to provide a quick display of the pdf document without forcing the user to download it.

Answer (score -1):

es simplemente poner un: id="NombreCampo" y asignar igualmente un: runat="server" desde el código en el archivo .aspx, quedaría así:
< iframe id="NombreCampo" runat="server" width="400" height="500" style="border: none;">
eso sería lo visible al usuario en el código de la página.
desde el codigo de lado del servidor poner la cadena con el FTP: 
NombreCampo.Src = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=ftp://nombreUsuario:pass@ftp.samplesite.com/" + NombreArchivo + " & embedded=true";

¡listo

Comment: Please post your answer in _english_ only.